# Connecting database from flow

Tags: corda

How should I need to connect with the database from flow to fetch the data instead of vault querying?

1.Instead of using custom query criteria, I am planning to use query command(like SQL command) to fetch the data from database.

2.Is it possible?

3.If it is possible, how to achieve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`serviceHub.jdbcSession().prepareStatement()` or `serviceHub.withEntityManager {  }`

Comment: Hello @Dan Newton Can you give me an example code? because i m getting the exception("com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement, which is a closeable resource, has been detected during flow checkpointing. Restoring such resources across node restarts is not supported. Make sure code accessing it is confined to a private method or the reference is nulled out.")

Comment: For further details refer the link:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57095232/getting-exception-while-fetching-data-from-database-in-the-flow